# PHP counter variable stops incrementing

Tags: php, html

I'm practicing using PHP by creating a simple quiz webpage. I want to display each question one at a time (rather that all at once). I have used a counter variable, which will keep track of the current question number. The question which corresponds to the value held in the counter variable will be displayed.

This is what i have been able to do so far.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>game</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="Untitled2.ico">
</head>
<body>
<div id="middle">
<div id="quiz">
<form id="quiz2" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<fieldset>
<?php 
if (isset($_SESSION['count'])){

$_SESSION['count'] = 1;
echo $_SESSION['count'];
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

++$_SESSION['count'];  
echo $_SESSION['count'];
}
?>
<?php if ($_SESSION['count']==1) : ?>
    <p>Ok, we will start with a nice easy question first.</p>
    <p>What is your favourite colour?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="red" required="required">
    Red
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="black" required="required">
    Black
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="green" required="required">
    Green
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="orange" required="required">
    Orange
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="yellow" required="required">
    Yellow
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q1" value="blue" required="required">
    Blue
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if ($_SESSION['count']==2) : ?>
    <p>Ah...I see.</p>
    <p>Now try this one.</p>
    <p>What trait do you admire most in a person?</p>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="intelligence" required="required">
    Intelligence
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="ambition" required="required">
    Ambition
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="kindness" required="required">
    Kindness
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="determination" required="required">
    Determination
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="self-preservation" required="required">
    Self-preservation
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="hard-working" required="required">
    Hard-working
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="Q2" value="creativity" required="required">
    Creativity
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Next">
 <?php endif; ?>
</fieldset> 
</form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

So, each chunk of html (which displays the question) is either hidden or shown depending on the counter variable.

This works ok until the counter variable gets to 2, at which point it stops incrementing, and question 2 remains on the page.

I thought using a session variable would stop this i have obviously done something wrong.

Comment: did you try like this `$_SESSION['count']++;`

Comment: i did, and unfortunately it didn't make a difference.

Answer (score 1):

You always set your counter to `2`

In this line you check if the counter-variable is set. If **YES** you set it to `1`

```
if(isset($_SESSION['count'])){

  $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
  echo $_SESSION['count'];
}
```

And then you increment it when getting a `POST`:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

++$_SESSION['count'];  

echo $_SESSION['count'];

}
```

So `1 + 1 = 2` as we know.

I think you want to initilaze the counter when it's NOT set, so change

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['count'])){
  $_SESSION['count'] = 1;  
} 

echo $_SESSION['count'];
```

And then increment if on `POST`

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  $_SESSION['count']++;  
}

echo $_SESSION['count'];
```

Comment: for some reason, after making those changes, i just get 44 displayed on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You are messing up with this code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_SESSION['count'])){
  $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
 echo $_SESSION['count'];
}
```

The above code means if we have a value for session variable, overwrite it to `1`.

This should be:

```
<?php
if (! isset($_SESSION['count'])){
  $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
  echo $_SESSION['count'];
}
```

This code checks if there is a value for session variable.

If not, set it to `1`.

If yes, do nothing.

Comment: Now that i have done that, no questions are being displayed at all

Answer (score 0):

This part

```
if (isset($_SESSION['count'])){

$_SESSION['count'] = 1;
echo $_SESSION['count'];
}
```

Makes the counter 1, everytime you reload the page. You should use !isset (so a ! before the isset), to make it so that count will be set to 1 when the counter is NOT yet set.

Comment: Now, no questions are being displayed at all

Answer (score 0):

Mistake is in following code:

```
    <?php 
    if (isset($_SESSION['count'])){

    $_SESSION['count'] = 1;
    echo $_SESSION['count'];
   }
```

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) checks for varible is set or not. if it is set then it evalutes true and excutes if portion.

so change it to following:

```
    if (empty($_SESSION['count']))
    {
    }
```

[empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) is check for varaible is assgined or not and also check for that value is not 0,'0',' ' and empty.

if you want confusion for using [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) or [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) then consider following:

isset is only check for varible is declared or not.
if varible is decalred and has value 0,' '  then isset evaluates true and excutes if portion.

when empty is check for both its declartion and value.
if value of varible is 0,' ' then it evalutes true and excutes if portion.
if varible is not declare then also it return true.